# Rendering same text for multiple TextBlocks in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, text, rendering

So I have a ListView with a UniformGrid of 16 rows and 32 columns as it's ItemsPanelTemplate. ItemsSource is bound to an ObservableCollection of objects that have two properties: IsSelected and Value. Each cell in the UniformGrid contains a TextBlock whose Text property is bound to the Value Property of its respective item. Below this construct, I have a ScrollBar whose value ranges from 0 to 255. Adjusting this ScrollBar changes the Value Property of the selected items in this grid.

Now that I've painted that picture, here is the problem. The issue is when I have many slots selected, and change the value of the ScrollBar, it updates all of the TextBlocks at once, causing visible lag. I scoured the internet for a solution to this problem, reading many articles on improving rendering performance and such. I have tried using Glyphs to try and increase the speed of text rendering, which showed improvement, but the lag was still painfully visible.

If I can somehow render the text only once per value change, and copy it to all other selected slots, I think this would improve performance. Is there a way to do this? If not, is there a different way I should be doing this kind of thing?

Comment: This could be hit or miss but sometimes when you have these kinds of draggable scroller/slider elements in a UI, dragging will want to spam the event queue with work to do refreshing UI elements. A potential solution is to avoid directly refreshing these elements and introduce a timer or something else executed in between event processing that will only trigger these refreshes at regular intervals. That makes it so you don't end up queuing a boatload of cascading requests to update UI elements which have to be processed individually...

Comment: ... this doesn't actually speed up the individual refreshes, but it can sometimes drastically improve the perception of speed by doing the refreshes at regular intervals and not spamming the queue (you might be doing 100 times more work than the human eye can perceive, e.g.). You might not actually need to optimize the redrawing so much as just reduce the amount of excessive drawing work being queued. In your case, since the refreshes are happening kind of behind your back, you might be able to defer changes to values which trigger refreshes at fixed intervals between event-processing.

Answer (score 1):

If not all of them are visible you could look at reducing your lag by looking into using VirtualizingStackPanel property.

```
VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
     VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
```

http://miteshsureja.blogspot.com/2011/05/virtualizing-stack-panel-in-wpf.html

Additionally, if it's because of the speed at which a scrollbar can change value, and the draw of the UI just can't keep up....you could use a Timer that gets restarted anytime the scrollbar/slider changed event is called.

Once the timer elapses (lets say you pick 1 second) without being restarted by the change event, then it updates the value that the boxes are all binded to so that it only updates once the user stops moving the scrollbar/slider.

Comment: All slots are visible. I will try the timer suggestion tomorrow. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Is this no different than setting the Delay property of the Binding?

Comment: Should function similarly, just one gives you control. Was Delay working for you?

Comment: It gets rid of the lag on transition yes, but immediate response is required unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be a a way to easily copy the rendered text to other TextBlocks. The only way to increase render performance whilst maintaining immediate response was to switch to Glyphs. Will update answer if I find a way to render text once, and copy it to the remaining Glyphs.